# Entity Framework 1 - Closing DB Connection

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, database-connection

Do we need to close DB connection if we are using Entity Model 1 with Web Forms ?

Comment: Can you provide a code example? I think a good thumb of rule is, if you create the connection yourself, you should close it yourself. But  the easiest and safest way is to use a [`using` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to create and dispose the connection.

Comment: @atticae, We only use Entity model's object 
_db = new MyEntities();

Comment: So you must dispose the `_db`

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, If I set the _db in my constructor of DAL class, what should I do then?

Comment: Make your DAL disposable and dispose the context in its Dispose method. Dispose DAl.

Comment: If you create the _db in the constructor, you will still have an open database connection for the whole lifetime of the DAL class. That's not a good idea, you should create it where you need it and dispose it right afterwards.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, OK got it, but what if I don't dispose the entities object, when the connection will be released?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, I have implemented the change .. now I call DAL's Dispose after using DAL. But another problem has started now. When I call objUser.GroupsReference.Load(); to get User's group Id .. I get an exception that object context is already disposed. How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `using`-Statement to make sure your EDM model gets properly disposed after usage. EF will cover closing the connection then, if necessary.

```
using(MyEntities _db = new MyEntities())
{
    // do stuff here
    // ...
} // _db gets automagically disposed here
```

Comment: If I set the _db in my constructor of DAL class, what should I do then?

Comment: You _could_ just call _db.Dispose() yourself after you are done, but maybe you should rather rethink your design. What do you need the variable for, when the connection is closed anyway? Why do you need to create it in the constructor, if you do not work with it until here? If you use it multiple times, you should always create a new instance instead of keeping the old one alive, because that could mean you are keeping the connection open. Thats something you don not want to do.

Comment: OK got it, but what if I don't dispose the entities object, when the connection will be released?

Comment: @eFriend It may potentially leave the connection open and keep resources open in the database connection  pool.  We've been getting random connection errors that are probably related to this.  Otherwise, it will eventually get garbage collected, but you never know the exact time that may happen, hence the connection can stay active (may not be open, but instantiated) because of it.